# Magento 2: After custom cookie is created all pages default to home page

Tags: magento2, cookie

I'm trying to add a custom cookie that will save the current cart item total so an external CMS can access and display it.  However, when the cookie is created successfully, any subsequent page loads just default to the store home page.

namespace MyVendor\Cartsession\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class UpdateCartCount implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    protected $checkoutSession;

```
/**
 * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
 */
public function __construct(
    CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager,
    CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
    ) {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
}

public function execute(Observer $observer) {

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();

    $cartData = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    $totalQuantity = count($cartData);

    $totals = $quote->getTotals();
    $duration = 3000;


    $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
        ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
        ->setDuration($duration)
        ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
        ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());


    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
        'M2Cart',
        $totalQuantity,
        $metadata
    );


}
```

}